# Why do spin locks make no sense on a single CPU?

Tags: multithreading, synchronization, multiprocessing, cpu, mutex

While reading *Operating System Three Easy Pieces* I found the following sentence:

> "To work correctly on a single processor, it requires a preemptive scheduler (i.e., one that will interrupt a thread via a timer, in
>   order to run a different thread, from time to time). Without
>   preemption, spin locks don’t make much sense on a single CPU, as a
>   thread spinning on a CPU will never relinquish it."

Why does a thread spinning on a single CPU will never relinquish it even though multi-threading is supported for a single CPU? Is it because spin-lock simply wastes too much CPU resources in this case? How does the number of CPU cores affect the performances of different locks such as mutex and spin locks?

Comment: Note the part where it says: *"Without preemption, ..."*

Comment: ohhh.. got it! thanks!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On a single CPU, single-core CPU you can still have [thread](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_(computing)) [multi-tasking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_multitasking) (multi-threading), with the caveat that only one thread can typically execute at once due to the lack of multiple execution units.  Without multiple execution units (hardware multi-threading), the hardware relies on a "[software multi-threading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_(computing)#Single_vs_Multiprocessor_systems)" strategy defined by the kernel -- low level operating system software to determine what to execute and when.

[Preemption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preemption_(computing)) is a strategy that involves a more active shepherding (so to speak) these multiple streams of execution along a single path commonly implement in part via the use timer based interrupts.  The opposite of preemption -- [cooperative scheduling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooperative_multitasking) -- adopts a more laissez-faire approach, leaving it up to the active threads to signal it's complete.

As a result the cooperative scheduling scheme allows one thread process's thread to hold on to the only computing resource (in this case) for longer:

[image]

But what if the active thread in such a scheme were to try to stay active forever?  That's what happens here, in essence.

A spinlock is an active wait to lock a requested resource.  The thread will just sit there waiting for whatever other thread locked the resource it wants to relinquish it.  As the text indicates that the hardware situation will only allow one active thread at a time, if the requested resource is locked, this implies it is locked by an inactive thread.

Without preemption it is up to the threads to decide when to stop executing.  Hence, when the active thread spinlocks, it will sit there eternally -- what is known as hang.  To stop this the user would likely be forced to physically turn off the system clearing the cache/dynamic memory.

With preemptive scheduling threads are implemented as [time slices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preemption_(computing)#Time_slice).  When accessing a particular resources is requisite before further work can be complete in a thread the [spinlock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spinlock) -- a busy wait -- makes sense.

With preemption the kernel will automatically [force context switch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_switch) after a specified amount of time, so even with a single CPU there won't be a hang.  Eventually the thread with the resource [lock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock_(computer_science)) will get some time and release its resource.  When the spinlock thread gets its next scheduled time, it will then be able to lock the resource and continue.

Overall this means less hang.

However, spinlock can still suffer more complex issues with preemptive scheduling, such as deadlock... when two threads are each spinlocked while holding each others' resources:

[image]

However, such cases are often avoidable via kernel safeguards on resource locking requests.

In a perfect world, cooperative scheduling with careful thread design could potentially lead to a bit faster execution of critical processes.  Hence it was a common approach in lean older OSes like Mac OS and Windows 3.x.  With the increase in computational demands, though, it has become harder to avoid the downsides of cooperative scheduling, hence virtually all modern operating system kernels use a preemptive scheduler.

Comment: Thank you for providing some insight

Comment: Glad to help!  Took me a while to hunt down satisfactory pictures, but I think those particular ones provide some good visual ties to the discussion.